# Android MVP retain presenter on orientation change

Tags: android, mvp, screen-orientation, persistent, presenter

I am implementing MVP for Login module in one of my project with the help of  MVP sample from [Google Sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp). In my login module I am verifying user credentials by calling web service . On orientation change activity is getting recreated and hence the presenter too,so not able to update the UI after getting the result from the webservice. 
At present I am using Fragment for Login UI and I am using `setRetainInstance(true);` in Fragment's onCreate() method. Is this a good approach  or what is the best approach to retain presenter?

Comment: I am retaining the presenter via Dagger. You can see an example implementation at [Android Ribot Boilerplate](https://github.com/ribot/android-boilerplate) app.

Comment: Consider using Loaders.